# ¿Cómo personalizar una variable de entorno en Laravel?

Tags: laravel

En el archivo `.env` de Laravel existen varias variables, yo estoy requiriendo agregar una personalizada, pero no sé como lograrlo.

Agregué un nuevo archivo llamado `theme.php` al directorio `config` en él agregué el siguiente código:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

    return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Theme
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    'theme' => env('THEME'),

];
```

En el archivo `.env` aguegué mi variable con su respectivo valor

```
THEME=blue
```

Y en la vista estoy tratando de leer el valor de la variable pero no llega, está vacía

```
@extends('layouts.'.config('theme.THEME').'-theme-app')
```

Si uso este código

```
@extends('layouts.'.config('theme', 'THEME').'-theme-app')
```

Me muestra el siguiente error

```
Array to string conversion
```

También ejecuté los siguientes comandos después de hacer lo que describí en el texto anterior

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
composer dump-autoload
```

PD: Intenté agregándola en el archivo `config/app` y tampoco funcionó. Estoy usando Laravel 9

Comment: as intentado utilizar const.php?  dentro de config?

Comment: Hola, de qué manera? no veo un archivo con ese nombre.

Comment: Sería `config('theme.theme')`. El primer theme es el nombre del archivo, y el segundo la clave a la que quieres acceder. No olvides limpiar la cache cada vez que modificas el .env l algún config

Comment: Gracias, debía limpiar el caché cada vez que cambio el .env